# Adding a setting to category configuration

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.6

I want to add a few admin settings to the Catalog/Manage Categories screen, I've grepped various directories but most of the site is accessed by FTP, where is the XML file that controls the options on this screen?

Edit: I have downloaded the entire site and grepped through it but can't find the one specific phrase that would definitely be there ('Secondary Category Link'), surely it's controlled by the same normal config settings (a system.xml file?)

Could someone please explain if/why I'm wrong rather than just voting down...

Comment: Are you talking Configuration Settings or Category Settings? Your question isnt quite clear on that.

Comment: Hey Ben,  Thanks for the reply, Category settings, when you're creating new product categories, so you've got 'Name', 'Is Active', 'Thumbnail Image', 'Description', etc, I want to add a few more settings to that.  Sorry it sounded clearer in my head!

Comment: Magento can be confusing. You think you have it figured out and it will throw you a curve.

Comment: Hey Ben, answer's fantastic thanks!  haha there I was thinking this would be easy/straightforward....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to add category attributes. The reason you are not finding them in code is that they are setup in the database.

Create a custom module with a setup script that adds attributes to categories. Once you have set up the attributes, you can use the normal getters and setters to access and update the data.

I could dig out some code, but a quick google search found this blog entry that appears promising for what you want to do: http://www.meteorify.com/2013/03/quick-tip-adding-custom-category-attributes-to-magento/

Or, here is a stack overflow question/answer that might help: [Magento 1.7 Add attribute to category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13336112/magento-1-7-add-attribute-to-category)